# Envoy as proxy to public internet services

Tags: envoyproxy

How can I configure Envoy as a proxy to public internet services, such that each path might route to a different service? For example:

```
http://foo.example.com/service1/* -> http://somewhere.com/*
http://foo.example.com/service2/* -> http://somewhereelse.com/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your envoy proxy is accessible at `http://foo.example.com`, you can use a config like this :

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service1"
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: service1
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service2"
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: service2
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
  - name: service1
    connect_timeout: 15s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service1
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: somewhere.com
                port_value: 80
  - name: service2
    connect_timeout: 15s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service2
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: somewhereelse.com
                port_value: 80
```

The important parts are :

- `prefix_rewrite: "/"` to rewrite `http://foo.example.com/service1/stuff` to `http://somewhere.com/stuff` (in fact, to remove `/service1`)
- `auto_host_rewrite: true` to add a `Host` header during forwarding (hostname of the upstream host of the cluster)

Comment: Have you by any chance figured out the answer to this question? I was curious to know the same thing

Comment: @AviDave this is the answer to the question asked by the OP :)

Comment: Ohh man, I was so caught up in my own question, I thought this was it I should have read a bit more carefully hahaha. It's interesting because I have been trying to find a way to route messages to a https host, so I have been trying to figure out if it is best Terminate TLS or passthrough TLS. I am not sure how that is done, and if you do have any insights, please let me know :)

Comment: You can find docs about TLS termination or passthrough here: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.23.0/start/sandboxes/tls. Do not hesitate to ask a new and separate question to expose in details your issue :)